# How many ways to pick four increasing numbers from 1 through 39?

Tags: combinatorics

Say there's a bin of balls numbered 1 through 39, how many ways are there to pick 4 increasing numbers in a row?

First I figured that it would be a permutation without repetition problem, so I got that the number of ways of picking 4 different balls without considering increase is $$\frac{39!}{4!(39-4)!} = 82,250.999966$$

Then I thought I need to divide by some factor that changes the problem from any order to only increasing order which I thought might be `4!`, so I got: $$\frac{82,250.999966}{4!} =  3,427.124998$$ and rounded down to get $3,427$. I'm terrible at these counting problems so I probably did this wrong. Can someone help me out please?

Comment: Sorry, how can a binomial symbol be non-integral?  Your first expression, $\binom {39}4$ is $82251$.  No rounding involved.

Comment: I thought that was weird, I guess my calculator didn't handle it well for some reason

Comment: And, to be clear, that's also the answer to the original question.  Every unordered group of $4$ can be sorted in a unique way so as to be increasing.  No need to divide by anything.

Comment: Ahh, don't know why I didn't realize that, thanks.